# Extracting a tar file with folders starting with /

Tags: python, archive, tarfile

I am writing a program in python and using `tarfile` to extract tarfiles. Some of these tarfiles contain folders which start with a `/` or (Alternatively for windows `\`) which cause problems (files are extracted to wrong place). How can I get around this issue and make sure that the extraction ends up in correct place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs for `tarfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall) explicitly warn about such a scenario. Instead you need to iterate over the content of the tar file and `extract` each file individually:

```
import os
import tarfile

extract_to = "."
tfile = tarfile.open('so.tar')

members = tfile.getmembers()
for m in members:
    if m.name[0] == os.sep:
        m.name = m.name[1:]
    tfile.extract(m, path=extract_to)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try extractall() method? As I remeber one of the this method arguments contains information where archive should be extracted.

Comment: Yes but if there is a \ infront of the file inside, it messes up everything.. (there is also a warning about this in official docs)